# How to fix: Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, junit, mockito

I have updated Maven from `4.0.0-alpha-3` to `4.0.0-alpha-12`. Build is failing with the following error:

```
Java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;
```

Spring version: `2.7.18`

Dependencies:

- Junit `4.13.2`
- Junit-jupiter: `5.8.2`
- Spring-boot-starter-test: `2.7.18` (pulls in mockito-core: `4.5.1`)

Please provide any suggestions on this.

Comment: Full pom file would be helpful.best a link to a example project... JDK version?

Comment: Jdk version is 1.8

Comment: Example project anywhere?